# Why doesn't Space.SE have an icon?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderator

Some SE sites have icons and emblems while others do not. At first glance the SE sites with icons seem more established. Why doesn't Space.SE use icons yet? What would make a good icon?

What creative picture existing or newly designed emblem would be a good fit for this site?

Can we base this on votes?

[image]

[What is the universal emblem that represents space exploration?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34402/what-is-the-universal-emblem-that-represents-space-exploration)

Comment: isn't it just because space is still in beta? in your own screenshot Earth Science and Astronomy don't have custom icons

Comment: @user17915 I'm not sure

Comment: Those icons are 24x24 pixels, the designs you've made so far become illegible when resized to 24x24.

Comment: https://www.favicon.cc/?action=icon_list&tag_id=71 - Favicons are what is used for these symbols, AFAIK. https://www.favicon.cc/?action=icon&file_id=854311 would be a cool one :).

Comment: The rocket concept. That's more emblematic of space exploration than a satellite.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why doesn't Space.SE use icons yet?

A simple explanation is because the site is still in Beta. All Beta SE sites (except the sponsored one, like QuantumComputing.SE and ArtificialIntelligence.SE) will have the generic beta theme, including favicon with an SE-bubble with either letter or symbol inside it.

The more complex detail is... since [Design-Independent Graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754), sites can have graduation without site-design. You can see the list of graduated SE sites without site-design (including favicon) on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290363/241919).

FWIW, all of you are free to propose any site icons for this community (e.g. [Lifehacks.SE had a short discussion on that](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60)), but until this site has graduated, and until SE Design Team continue the site-design project, this discussion might be moot.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with a little bit of moot questioning and [answering](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1195/27056) once in a while ;-)

Comment: Very nice icon. Can you do one for here as well?

Comment: I took your example and made another answer. Do you like it?

Comment: Note also that the whole graduation process [appears to be broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322781/275243), at least for the moment. Maybe they'll fix it in six to eight weeks...

Answer (score 2):

Here is my redrawn emblem taken from a few sources.

Smaller icon:
[image]

I updated this one to include my other answers and designs:

I took Andrew T and ami suggestion and came up with this icon. If they wish to post an icon answer I will remove mine if it is similar. My flame is a little off center but if you like it and is wanted I will redraw it better.

[image][image][image][image][image]

This is what my latest might look like on the site.

[image]

This was done with favicon.cc as requested:[image]  https://www.favicon.cc/?action=icon_list&tag_id=71

Comment: Space exploration can be manned or unmanned, remote or in situ, but it always requires [escape] velocity, so the common 'rocket icon' (with fire, fins, and a window for 'observation'), seems pretty good to me.

Comment: @amI thats an answer google spacecraft icon

Comment: The smaller icon looks great! However, what does it look like when you shrink it to the size of the tab icon (~16x16 pixels?) A candidate icon should work visually at different scales. I'd add some color too, at least for the dish, panels, and body. Examples of other sites: https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid I'm not sure how to show them at their smallest sizes though.

Comment: @uhoh I noticed the aviation has a 2 part emblem and an icon. I will think on this some more.

Comment: @Hobbes should I delete this answer based on the comments, edit with a new helmet design or create a new answer with a redesigned helmet and suit emblem. The helmet would be the emblem but given the suit on the page like aviation.

Comment: @Muze you can test if it would work as a favicon using http://favicon.cc

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn i did thanks.